# User management and Commenting system for website

Tags: single-sign-on

I am working on a news media website, and I am looking to add feature to allow users to register, login and make comments.

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c0hQ.png) (New York Times login/register screen)

May I know what options are available, what are the common approaches publishers would choose ?

So far I have been looking at:

1. AWS Cognito: Allows to create own user directory, and authenticate.
2. Disquss SSO: also implemented commenting.
3. In house development: Code a new microservice to manage user directory and store/serve comments, alternatively using AWS Lambda. I am very keen to go down that path, [example](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth), but this might costs a lot to develop + maintain.

User data security is my top consideration, I would prefer to use a separate system to store user data. Either a robust third party service or complete in house development of a new system.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These are web-standards for single sign on:

- OpenID
- OpenID Connect

Companies like Google and Facebook provide authentication using Google-/Facebook-accounts. As far as I know, Google uses OpenID Connect which is based on OAuth. However, I don't know if you don't have to store user data any more at all when using this.

I believe it's worth checking again if authentication and commenting should be combined, especially when using a third-party-solution. It makes it harder to change one of the two.

This could give you some more ideas: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations.